# error conexión base de datos en mamp y nodejs

Tags: mysql, nodejs, visual-studio

tengo el siguiente problema: Cree una base con phpmyadmin en mamp y le agregue un usuario para poder hacer la conexión desde mi archivo app.js en visual studio code, el inconveniente es que sigo todos los pasos que veo en Internet, creo el archivo package json como se me indica, y creo un archivo app.js para hacer la conexión con mi base, pero siempre da el mismo error "[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... A continuación, adjunto las imágenes en este enlace de unidad: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-df1kYLSW60SxmmGlPTEe5vziSEKhimb En fin... no sé si hay que activar algo en mamp para dejar habilitada mi base, la verdad es que es la primera vez que trabajo con esta aplicación. Supongo que el error está en cómo se cree la base porque mis otros archivos, paquete json y app.js, parecen ser iguales a todos los demás. Le agradecería un montón de ayuda, soy principiante y ya llevo mucho tiempo con este problema. feliz día

Comment: Hola, vi las imagenes que enviaste y en el phpmyadmin el puerto se ve que es el 8889 y tú estás conectándote por el 3306, trata de ver si puedes revisar esa configuración y antes de intentar conectarte en node y si tienes el cliente mysql en tu consola, puedes intentar conectarte bash>mysql -u adrian -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P8889 (si ya estas en el 3306 no es necesario especificar el puerto)

Comment: Buenas noches Omar! espero estes teniendo una feliz noches. muchísimas gracias por   destacarme ese detallazo Omar, logre solucionar, te agradezco un moton. ahora tengo una pequeña duda, ya me apareció el mensaje "hola mundo " pero si cambio el mensaje, la consola no se actualiza ni nada y tenia entendido que la conexion con la base era a tiempo real y si modificaba algo, este se actualizaría pero creo que la consola finalizó proceso, te voy a mandar foto de lo que me sale para ver si es que me equivoco yo o que debo hacer.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1df1kYLSW60SxmmGlPTEe5vziSEKhimb. disculpa las molestias de ante mano, soy apenas principiante. muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Creo que el link que te envié no abre, aquí está de nuevo 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-df1kYLSW60SxmmGlPTEe5vziSEKhimb